# Receiving a 404 error from any website I attempt to pull data from

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm attempting to create a simple web app that pulls data from a website depending on user input, but no matter what URL I use, it produces a 404 error in the console.

Here's the code, there's nothing else relevant as I've changed my other code for testing to simply submit a basic URL that doesn't depend on user input, by calling the function as so:

```
httpGet(myUrl);

function httpGet(theUrl){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("definition").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What are the URLs you checked?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe various pages on http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/ , https://a1barry.github.io/ and https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/ for example

Comment: This is because the pages you tried to run the request has disabled Cross-Origin Requests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe how do I bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature, these third party pages might not want clients from other peoples apps to access that service as API but visit those pages directly. A solution can be using your own server as some kind of proxy. Your html-app will request your server, and your server access the remote service/website.

I see there is also a github page. Instead of having JSON files, you could wrap that data into a function-call and store as `.js` file (see jsonp). if the repo belongs to someone else, you can clone it into your own github page. But check if the license allow that.